# Direct sum, null space and range

Tags: linear-algebra

I encounter this problem in my homework. Does it mean I have to prove 3 if and only if statement. I have no clue, can anyone show me the entire proof. Thanks

Let T : R3 → R3 be a linear transformation. Prove the equivalence of the
following statements.

```
                   (i) R3 = N(T) ⊕ R(T);
                   (ii) N(T) = N(T^2);
                   (iii) R(T) = R(T^2).
```

(We write R3 = N(T) ⊕ R(T) if, for all v ∈ R3, there exists x ∈ N(T) and
y ∈ R(T) such that v = x + y, and N(T) ∩ R(T) = {0}.)

Comment: You can do as usual: Prove that (i) implies (ii), (ii) implies (iii), and (iii) implies (i).

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean I have to prove 3 if and only if statement

Yes.  However, you could just prove (for instance) that i implies ii, ii implies iii, and iii implies i.  If you think about it for a minute then you'll see why this gives you all three if-and-only-ifs.